# Why exactly is NirSoft's software not open source?

Tags: proprietary-code, source-code, closed-source

Apologies if this type of question isn't allowed here, but I am quite curious about this.

If you don't know, NirSoft is some sort of dev that has created a lot of software for use on Windows primarily. They've got everything from a browser cookie viewer to a BSOD dump viewer. All of these products are free as in price, and don't seem to collect any user data at all.

My question is, why has the source code for any of these pieces of software not been released? There seems to be nothing stopping Nir Sofer from just releasing the source code, so why not?

He has been inactive for quite a few years, but even when he was active he never released the source code. I really wish I could contact him, but I suspect his email is now defunct.

Comment: What answer are you looking for here other than "because the author chose not to release it as open source?" We can't read their mind.

Comment: Why don't you try to contact the author directly and ask?!! There is a contact form on his website.